# Regexp for robots.txt

Tags: regex, robots.txt

I am trying to set up my robots.txt, but I am not sure about the regexps.

I've got four different pages all available in three different languages. Instead of listing each page times 3, I figured I could use a regexp.

**nav.aspx**

**page.aspx/changelang** (might have a query string attached such as "?toLang=fr".)

**mypage.aspx?id** and 
 **login.aspx/logoff** (=12346?... etc - different each time)

! All four in 3 different languages, e.g:

**www.example.com/es/nav.aspx

www.example.com/it/nav.aspx

www.example.com/fr/nav.aspx**

Now, my question is: Is the following regexp correct?

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /*nav\.aspx$
Disallow: /*page.aspx/changelang
Disallow: /*mypage\.aspx?id
Disallow: /*login\.aspx\/logoff
```

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Regular Expressions are not allowed in robots.txt, but Googlebot (and some other robots) can understands some simple pattern matching:

Your robots.txt should look like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*nav.aspx$
Disallow: /*page.aspx/changelang
Disallow: /*mypage.aspx?id
Disallow: /*login.aspx/logoff
```

`User-agent` directive is valid with lower case `a`. You don't have to escape `.` or `/'.

You can read more about this here: [Block or remove pages using a robots.txt file](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449&from=40360&rd=1)