# How can I prevent Googlebot from crawling my Underscore client-side templates?

Tags: seo, underscore.js, google-search-console, googlebot, nofollow

In Google Webmaster Tools, under Crawl Errors/Other, we're seeing a 400 Error for URLs like this:

```
/family-tree/<%=tree.user_url_slug%>/<%=tree.url_slug%>
```

[image]

This is not a real URL, or a URL that we intended to be crawled. It is an Underscore/Backbone template:

```
<script type="text/template" class="template" id="template-trees-list">
  <% _.each(trees, function(tree) { %>
    <a href="/family-tree/<%=tree.user_url_slug%>/<%=tree.url_slug%>" rel="nofollow">
      <%= tree.title %>
    </a>
  <% }); %>
</script>
```

1. Why is Google crawling inside of the `script` block?
2. Why is Google ignoring the `rel="nofollow"` attribute?
3. Is there anything else we can do to keep Googlebot away from our Underscore templates?

UPDATE: I'm open to using robots.txt if I can find the right pattern that will keep the good pages and block the bad pages. For example, I want to keep `/surnames/Jones/queries` while blocking `/surnames/Jones/queries/<%=url_slug%>`. I have thousands like this. Looks like [Googlebot may support basic patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6306988/41820), though not full regexes.

UPDATE 2: Well, this doesn't get at the root cause, and it seems a bit brittle as a long-term solution, but I tested in GWT that the following robots.txt patterns will work:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /*url_slug%%3E$
Disallow: /*url_slug%%3E/$
```

Answer (score 1):

just block these via robots.txt and you'll be fine

Comment: I don't believe you can block *parts* of a page with robots.txt, which is what OP wants.

Comment: Updated the Question regarding robots.txt -- perhaps it's an option.