# robots.txt exclude paths with language

Tags: web, seo, robots.txt, noindex

If i for example want to disallow the following path on my page:
http://www.examplepage.com/en/testing

But not only the /en/ version, also /da/, /de/ etc. (you get my point).

How would i do that the smartest way? Without writing a disallow for the same pages in every language.

I tried:
Disallow: /*/testing 
and
Disallow: /*testing

But i found out that it also disallows other pages like:
http://www.examplepage.com/en/news-page/testing etc.

It should only disallow the path i specified in the beginning of my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using placeholders/RegExp in robots.txt is very limited and not reliable. See this question for more information: [Regexp for robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306763/regexp-for-robots-txt)

It's probably to best solution to list all languages separately or to write a script which outputs a list with all rules.